# Remove PR Merge, then Merge Later

Tags: git, git-merge

Several pull-requests have been merged into our develop branch. We have since discovered that a client of our code will be broken by one of the PRs that has been merged.

Ideally, there is a clean way to remove that one merge, leaving subsequent merges intact. Later, when the client has cleaned up their code, we would want to re-apply the PR merge.

Developers have continued to work on in the codebase, but we believe that removing the merged PR would not create significant conflicts.

Is removing that one PR cleanly and re-merging it later possible, and what steps would be necessary?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri It may be, although it does not mention preserving merges that occur after the revert.

Comment: I stand corrected, is does go into detail, pointing out that the _data_ changed by the merge is reverted, however the history is not. To re-apply the PR, you need to revert the revert, not apply the PR again.

Comment: Glad it helped you @Bex